# How to build Poco NET_SSL on Windows

Tags: openssl, poco-libraries

I want to use [Poco libraries](https://pocoproject.org/) to send email notifications from a Windows application running on various remote sites back to our head office. It seems that Poco uses [Open SSL](http://www.openssl.org) for TLS. The documentation on both projects is not the most user-friendly :-(

I'm having trouble getting anything related to the Poco `NetSSL_OpenSSL` source to build - I need `PocoNetSSL` .lib and DLL files, but can't generate them; I've tried building the samples, but they don't compile either due to path issues.

The Visual Studio project file for the samples suggests that it is expecting something external to provide the `INCLUDE` paths which would specify where `OpenSSL` is installed. What is that external thing? The [Poco documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html) suggests it should be the `INCLUDE` environment variable. For me it's not working. What might I be missing? (I'm building using VS 2015 Community on a Win7 64-bit machine).

I build using a `buildwin 140 rebuild` command. All sub-projects in the `components` file build correctly until the `Crypto` project. The build for that proceeds as follows:

```
 1>Project "S:\3rdparty\Poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs140.vcxproj" on node 1 (rebuild target(s)).
 1>_PrepareForClean:
     Deleting file "obj\Crypto\debug_shared\Crypto.tlog\Crypto.lastbuildstate".
   InitializeBuildStatus:
     Touching "obj\Crypto\debug_shared\Crypto.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
   ClCompile:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\CL.exe /c /I.\include /I..\Foundation\include /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _USRDLL /D Crypto_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /GF /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"obj\Crypto\debug_shared\\" /Fd"obj\Crypto\debug_shared\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue src\Cipher.cpp src\CipherFactory.cpp src\CipherImpl.cpp src\CipherKey.cpp src\CipherKeyImpl.cpp src\CryptoStream.cpp src\CryptoTransform.cpp src\DigestEngine.cpp src\OpenSSLInitializer.cpp src\RSACipherImpl.cpp src\RSADigestEngine.cpp src\RSAKey.cpp src\RSAKeyImpl.cpp src\X509Certificate.cpp
     X509Certificate.cpp
 1>src\X509Certificate.cpp(62): error C2027: use of undefined type 'x509_st' [S:\3rdparty\Poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs140.vcxproj]
     S:\3rdparty\OpenSSL\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl/ossl_typ.h(119): note: see declaration of 'x509_st'
```

Pretty clearly to me that is not including anything from `OpenSSL`. What is not clear to me is what should be included. The `OpenSSL` source distribution does contain a folder named `internal` that would help... but the binary distribution for Windows recommended by Poco (namely the `WinOpenSSL` product mentioned [here](https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html)) compiles away that "internal" folder. That seems right... but if so, that would mean the Poco source might be "wrong" in the way it is using `OpenSSL`. Is it? Mostly likely not. Either way there is a conflict here whose resolution is not obvious to me.

Comment: Please post how exactly you are trying to build and what errors you are getting, so perhaps someone will be able to help. The windows build documentation is clear: 

"start the buildwin.cmd script and pass as argument the version of visual studio (71, 80, 90, 100 or 110). You can customize what is being built by buildwin.cmd by passing appropriate command line arguments to it. Call buildwin.cmd without arguments to see what is available."

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use OpenSSL 1.1.0 which changed the API to 'hide' several structs including `x509_st` effective 2016-08 but Poco (or the version you have) hasn't been updated for that. If you can't update or otherwise fix Poco, use OpenSSL 1.0.2 which is still current and available from ShininglLight though not the 'latest and greatest'

Answer (score 0):

A year ago I gave up on this and used a different product, such is/was the state of the documentation.

I recently had cause to try again, and after much pain, found that I could get it to compile as follows:

- Download latest Poco distribution (1.9.0)
- Install OpenSSL 1.10 from [ShiningLight](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) directly inside the `Poco` folder, such that `...\Poco\OpenSSL` sits alongside `...\Poco\Crypto`
- get the contents of the `build` folder from the [Poco OpenSSL project on GitHub](https://github.com/pocoproject/openssl) and copy them into `...\Poco\OpenSSL\build`

  - I couldn't get the `build.ps1` script to run due to bad PowerShell installation on my PC, so made use of the binaries pre-compiled in the `build` folder
- customise the `buildwin.cmd` script to specify the location of `OpenSSL` as `...\Poco\OpenSSL`
- run the `buildwin.cmd` script with appropriate parameters

This built all the projects for me without any errors (a few warnings here and there only). Note that there is additional setup of a similar nature to compile the MySQL  & ODBC projects (i.e. install MySQL with ODBC options, customise the `buildwin.cmd` script to suit).